# Why I am not getting kernel panic message?

Tags: kernel-modules, kernel-panic

As I am not using `copy_to_user` and `copy_from _user` functions, the following kernel module should give kernel a panic message. But I am getting proper output.
Architecture is x86 on ubuntu 14.04 LTE.

```
$ sudo mknod /dev/mem_char c 61 0
$ sudo chmod 777 /dev/char
$ echo 123asa >/dev/mem_char
```

dmesg output:

```
[  494.821648] mem_driver: module license 'unspecified' taints kernel.
[  494.821653] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[  494.821678] mem_driver: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[  573.581104] data from user : 123asa
[  573.581104]  tushar!!
[  573.581104] eload
[  573.581104] t
[  573.581104] /bin/grub-script-check
[  573.581104] bkdf2
[  573.581104] e
```

Module code:

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/fs.h>
#include<linux/init.h>

ssize_t mem_read (struct file *, char __user *,size_t, loff_t *);
ssize_t mem_write (struct file *, const char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
int mem_open (struct inode *, struct file *);
int mem_release (struct inode *, struct file *);

int major_no=61;    //if major no=0 then dynamic mean kernel alocate it 

struct file_operations fops={
    .open=mem_open,
    .read=mem_read,
    .write=mem_write,
    .release=mem_release,
};

ssize_t mem_read (struct file *fp, char __user *buff,size_t len,  loff_t *off)
{
    printk("buffer :%s \n",buff);
    return 0;
}
ssize_t mem_write (struct file *fp, const char __user *buff, size_t len, loff_t *off)
{
    //  char kbuff;
    //  printk("Function name : %s \n",__func__);
    printk("data from user : %s\n",buff);
    //    kmalloc();      
    return len;
}
int mem_open (struct inode *ip, struct file *fp)
{
    // printk("Function name : %s \n",__func__);
    return 0;
}
int mem_release (struct inode *ip, struct file *fp)
{
    // printk("Function name : %s \n",__func__);
    return 0;
}
static int mem_init(void)
{
    int ret;
    //        printk("mem_init\n");
    ret =register_chrdev(major_no,"mem_driver",&fops);
    if(ret<0)
    {
        //       printk("registetation fails with major no : %d",major_no);
        return ret; 
    }
    // printk("mem_driver register with major no %d\n",major_no);      
    return 0;
}
static void mem_exit(void)
{
    //  printk("exit\n");
    unregister_chrdev(major_no,"mem_driver");   
}
module_init(mem_init);
module_exit(mem_exit);
```

Comment: why must it, please show your working.  C + kernel is definition of "undefined behaviour".  Linux runs on computers without MMU, you have not even told us what architecture you are running on.

Comment: Also this question sounds like it should be moved to stackoverflow (programming).  With the possible exception if you're trying to learn something specific about Linux architecture - e.g. what it means for security - and you're not trying to learning about Linux programming as such.

Comment: @sourcejedi : hi updated my code details please help me on this.module is registered with major no 61 and minor no 0 and have entry in /proc/devices

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for a kernel panic, since in your test the module printed data from an accessible address until a null was found (you should have used the length of the data to limit the printk).

**However,** you might try the same test another time and it would panic because your program (echo) has been paged out of memory! In such a case, accessing the data causes a page fault, which is the normal way to have the data paged back into memory, but because you have not used `copy_from_user()`, the kernel has to assume the page fault is a programming error and will panic.

This is the primary value of using `copy_from_user()` on many architectures: it marks this bit of code as potentially producing "legal" page faults, which should be handled normally (as when they occur in user space) as a request to page back in data. Otherwise it is just a sort of optimised `memcpy()`.

The function also does some preliminary checks on the validity of the address.  See [this explanation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-kernel-memory-access/).

---

The `echo 123asa` is conceptually implemented in user space by code like

```
char data[1024];
memcpy(data,"123asa\n",7);
write(1,data,7);
```

where the string copied into `data` is 7 characters long, and has no reason to end with an 8th null character `\0`. So `data[7]` onwards will contain random uninitialised data.

When in your module you do `printk("%s\n",buff)`, the format `%s` will print characters from buff until it reaches a null character, which could be a long way away. You should instead restrict the length to that provided as in

```
printk("%*s\n",len,buff);
```

Comment: will u explain more  "untill a null was found" mean? please

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: still no panic message i replaced printk("data from user : %s \n",buff) to printk("data from user : %*s \n",len,buff) output :data from user : (null)*

Comment: You will not get a panic unless your program is swapped out of memory at the time of the printk, which is pretty unlikely.

Comment: What you  mean swapped out of memory ? And how I can get panic in the above same code ? Because with same concept (the one I written code)it is excepted that panic occur

Comment: Perhaps you should start a new post explaining what your real original problem is, and you can refer to this post to show how you are trying to debug it.